# How to presentModalViewController above subviews

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I currently have a subview covering the whole screen and with a UIButton on. When I press the button, I bring up a different view for sending an email using `[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];` this brings up the new view (viewcontroller) but behind the subview. If I press a button to `removeFromSuperview` and the subview dissapears, then the email viewcontroller is visible.

Is it possible to set a Z-index or something when using `presentModalViewController`?

I don't want to remove the subview before it slides up. I want it to remain there the whole time while the user types his email etc. So when he is done, the subview still shows.

---

**Showing the subview (which has the button on)**

```
[self.view.superview addSubview:pinSpecsView];
```

**Clicking the button**

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Email", @"Message", nil];
popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
[popupQuery showInView:self.view];
[popupQuery release];
```

**Showing the email controller after "email" was selected**

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    ....
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be adding pinSpecsView to self.view instead of self.view.superview.

```
[self.view addSubview:pinSpecsView];
```

To change Z order of subviews use sendSubviewToBack: bringSubviewToFront: methods.

Comment: Haha, I see now that it's kinda obvious - adding the view on top of the superview. Thanks for pointing it out!